# Simplify expressions with PolyGamma (Special Function) and complex number

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions, complex

Integrate the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) from 0 to $\pi\,,$ will get $\pi\,,$ which can be written as

$$\int_0^\pi \left( \frac{\sin(nt/2)}{\sin(t/2)} \right)^2 \,dt = n\pi$$

We can simply verify the equation by

**Input:**

```
Integrate[(Sin[n t/2]/Sin[t/2])^2, {t, 0, Pi}]~Table~{n, 10} // Timing
```

**Output:**

```
{2.17188, {π, 2π, 3π, 4π, 5π, 6π, 7π, 8π, 9π, 10π}}
```

Now let's do the formal calculation with the *bizarre* MMA.

**Input:**

```
Integrate[(Sin[n t/2]/Sin[t/2])^2, {t, 0, Pi}, 
Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers] // Timing
%[[-1]] ~ FunctionExpand ~ (Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers)
% // FullSimplify
```

The last one of **Out[1]:**

```
-(1/2) I E^(-I n π) (1 + E^(2 I n π) + 
2 E^(I n π) n π Cot[n π] + n PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - n/2] - 
n PolyGamma[0, -(n/2)] + E^(2 I n π) n PolyGamma[0, n/2] - 
E^(2 I n π) n PolyGamma[0, (1 + n)/2])
```

[image]

### <del>Question</del> (All Solved ✅)

Q1. What is the approach to get rid of these complicated outputs? Or how to simplify them into $n\pi$?

Q2. Why it take so long to calculate? Any accelerate method? (Solved by @bob-hanlon and @akku14)

Many thanks!

**P.S.** `FindSequenceFunction` is pointless.

---

## Solution of Q1

```
f[e_] := Count[e, _PolyGamma, Infinity]
Integrate[(Sin[n t/2]/Sin[t/2])^2 // TrigReduce, {t, 0, Pi}]
FullSimplify[%, ComplexityFunction -> f]
FullSimplify[%, n ∈ Integers]
```

(Chance encounter in 2017-12-31 15:00, when reading [the penultimate one](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Simplification.html) in [this topic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AlgebraicManipulationOverview.html) in the official document~)

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction[
 Integrate[(Sin[n t/2]/Sin[t/2])^2, {t, 0, Pi}]~Table~{n, 10}, n]`

Comment: Note that the integral can be reformulated in terms of the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind (`ChebyshevU[]`).

Comment: `Table[2 Integrate[(ChebyshevU[n - 1, Cos[t]])^2, {t, 0, Pi/2}], {n, 10}]`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the knowledge, though Mma doesn't perform symbolic computation for this. 

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the request for an acceleration method.

```
$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)

Integrate[(Sin[n t/2]/Sin[t/2])^2, {t, 0, Pi}]~
  Table~{n, -5, 5} // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.684515, {5 π, 4 π, 3 π, 2 π, π, 0, π, 2 π, 3 π, 4 π, 5 π}} *)
```

Note that the integrals are `Abs[n] π` rather than `n π`

You can accelerate the integration for general `n` using [`TrigReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigReduce.html)

```
(int[n_] = 
   Integrate[(Sin[n t/2]/Sin[t/2])^2 // TrigReduce, {t, 0, Pi}] // 
       ComplexExpand // FullSimplify // FunctionExpand // 
    FullSimplify) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {12.12901, (1/2)*(2 + n*Pi*Cot[(n*Pi)/2] - 
        n*(PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - n/2] - 2*PolyGamma[0, n/2] + 
             PolyGamma[0, (1 + n)/2]))*Sin[n*Pi]} *)
```

This representation is `Indeterminate` for integer `n`; however, the limits provide the expected results.

```
int[1]

(* Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

Indeterminate *)

Table[Limit[int[n], n -> m], {m, -5, 5}]

(* {5 π, 4 π, 3 π, 2 π, π, 0, π, 2 π, 3 π, 4 π, 5 π} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply TrigReduce to the integrand an you get the integral quite fast. For unknown reasons the integral has singularities at n, therefore apply Limit.

```
(int[n_] = Integrate[(Sin[n t/2]/Sin[t/2])^2 // TrigReduce, {t, 0, Pi}, 
                      Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]) // Timing

(*     {10.094, -(1/2)
   I E^(-I n \[Pi]) (1 + 2 E^(I n \[Pi]) n \[Pi] Cot[n \[Pi]] + 
   n PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - n/2] - n PolyGamma[0, -(n/2)] + 
   E^(2 I n \[Pi]) (1 + n PolyGamma[0, n/2] - 
   n PolyGamma[0, (1 + n)/2]))}     *)

Table[Limit[int[n], n -> j] // FullSimplify, {j, 0, 10}]

(*     {0, Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi, 4 Pi, 5 Pi, 6 Pi, 7 Pi, 
         8 Pi, 9 Pi, 10 Pi}     *)
```